# Modify Arabic letters printed using thermal printer

Tags: android, printing, arabic, arabic-support

I managed to print Arabic strings with a thermal printer. However, the characters are reversed (written from left to right not from right to left).
I solved that by inverting the characters of the string and it did well.
Now, I have a new problem because some characters at the end of the arabic words are in the wrong shape as in the attached photo.

[image]

How can I solve that?

The word in the first line should be "السلام" not as shown.

The right word in the second line should be "النوع" not as shown.

This is my code to print

```
 void sendData() throws IOException {
        try {
            byte[] ALLINEA_CT = {0x1B, 0x61, 0x01}; //text to center

            String title = new StringBuilder("السلام").reverse().toString()+ '\n';
            mmOutputStream.write(ALLINEA_CT);
            mmOutputStream.write(title.getBytes("ISO-8859-6"));


            String kind =new StringBuilder("النوع").reverse().toString();
            String number = new StringBuilder("العدد").reverse().toString();
            String cost = new StringBuilder("التكلفة").reverse().toString();
            String BILL = "";
            BILL = BILL+ "-----------------------------\n";
            BILL = BILL + String.format("%1$4s %2$4s %3$17s",cost,number,kind);
            mmOutputStream.write(BILL.getBytes("ISO-8859-6"));


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

This is how  a connection is made

```
      OutputStream mmOutputStream;
      InputStream mmInputStream;
      BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
      BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
      BluetoothDevice mmDevice;


void findBT() {

        try {
            mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

            if(mBluetoothAdapter == null) {

            }

            if(!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                Intent enableBluetooth = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                startActivityForResult(enableBluetooth, 0);
            }

            Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();

            if(pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
                for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {

                    if (device.getName().equals(printername)) {
                        mmDevice = device;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }


        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



    // tries to open a connection to the bluetooth printer device
    void openBT() throws IOException {
        try {

            // Standard SerialPortService ID
            UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
            mmSocket = mmDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
            mmSocket.connect();
            mmOutputStream = mmSocket.getOutputStream();
            mmInputStream = mmSocket.getInputStream();


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: People will want to see how exactly you printed it (i.e. show code). You likely missed a step (like set directionality). Reversing the string is _not_ how to do it.

Comment: I will add the code I used

Comment: I also did not find another way to print from right to left. is there ?

Comment: @Amadan Here is the code

Comment: @Amadan been added in the post

Comment: Without knowing what printer you're using, it seems POS printers (which I assume is the thermal printer in question) are kind of dumb. It may be possible [UTF-8 to CP864 (arabic) conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28982577/utf-8-to-cp864-arabic-conversion) and the discussion [here](https://github.com/qzind/tray/pull/339) might help. Turns out, for some printers, reversing the string might be how you do it, after all.

Comment: Yes it's a POS printer

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to create a bitmap with your text and print it (most of thermal printers print bitmaps).
Example:

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(256+128, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
String text = "السلام";
canvas.drawText(text, 20, 20, new Paint());
printImage(bitmap);
```

I am using this code to print images https://github.com/MFori/Android-Bluetooth-Printer

Comment: This solution works but letters and words are pixelized which won't give satisfaction to customers who receive their orders' bills.